# TreeSet only adding one value?

Tags: java, collections, set, treeset

I am new to Java Collections. I have three classes namely **MyData, Initializer and SetBasics**

I have created a HashSet and a TreeSet. Now the problem is HashSet is working fine but TreeSet is only storing one value.

Here are my classes

**Class MyData**

`package collectionsWorkUp.setDemos;

public class MyData implements Comparable{

```
MyData(){   
}

MyData(String n, String p, String eM, long mn, char s){
    name = n;
    profession = p;
    email = eM;
    mobileNo = mn;
    sex =  s;
}


private String name;
private String profession;
private String email;
private long mobileNo;
private char sex;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getProfession() {
    return profession;
}
public void setProfession(String profession) {
    this.profession = profession;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public long getMobileNo() {
    return mobileNo;
}
public void setMobileNo(long mobileNo) {
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
}
public char getSex() {
    return sex;
}
public void setSex(char sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(MyData o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}
`

**Class Initializer**

package collectionsWorkUp.setDemos;

public class Initializer {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Initializing");

    SetBasics operate = new SetBasics();

    operate.DataInSet();
    operate.printDataInSet(operate.getUsersInHash());

    System.out.println("\n\nPrinting Data in Tree Set--------------------");
    operate.printDataInSet(operate.getUsersInTree());

    System.out.println("\n\n--------Program Terminated----------");

}
```

}

**Class SetBasics**

package collectionsWorkUp.setDemos;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SetBasics{

```
    private Set<MyData> usersInHash = new HashSet<MyData>();
    private Set<MyData> usersInTree =  new TreeSet<MyData>();

    MyData d1= new MyData(d1's data -data include name, #, profession etc check MyData Class);
    MyData d2=  new MyData(d2's data);
    MyData d3=  new MyData(d3's data);
    MyData d4= new MyData(d4's data);
    MyData d5= new MyData(d5's data);
    MyData d6= new MyData(d6's data);
    MyData d7= new MyData(d7's data);
    MyData nullUser = null;

    public Set<MyData> getUsersInHash() {
        return usersInHash;
    }

    public Set<MyData> getUsersInTree() {
        return usersInTree;
    }

public SetBasics(){ }

public void DataInSet(){

    {
        System.out.println("Adding Data in HashSet");
        System.out.println("Data in HashSet Before Adding Element:" + usersInHash.size());
        setDataInSet(nullUser);
        System.out.println("Data in HashSet After Adding Element:" + usersInHash.size());
        setDataInSet(d7);
        System.out.println("Data in HashSet After Adding Element:" + usersInHash.size());
        setDataInSet(d6);
        System.out.println("Data in HashSet After Adding Element:" + usersInHash.size());
        setDataInSet(d5);
        System.out.println("Data in HashSet After Adding Element:" + usersInHash.size());
        setDataInSet(d4);
        System.out.println("Data in HashSet After Adding Element:" + usersInHash.size());
        setDataInSet(d3);
        System.out.println("Data in HashSet After Adding Element:" + usersInHash.size());
        setDataInSet(d2);
        System.out.println("Data in HashSet After Adding Element:" + usersInHash.size());
        setDataInSet(d1);
        System.out.println("Data in HashSet After Adding Element:" + usersInHash.size());
        setDataInSet(null);
        System.out.println("Data in HashSet After Adding Element:" + usersInHash.size());
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Adding Data in TreeSet");
        System.out.println("Users in Tree after Before Data:"+usersInTree.size());
        setDataInTreeSet(d7);
        System.out.println("Users in Tree after Adding Data:"+usersInTree.size());
        setDataInTreeSet(d6);
        System.out.println("Users in Tree after Adding Data:"+usersInTree.size());
        setDataInTreeSet(d5);
        System.out.println("Users in Tree after Adding Data:"+usersInTree.size());
        setDataInTreeSet(d4);
        System.out.println("Users in Tree after Adding Data:"+usersInTree.size());
        setDataInTreeSet(d3);
        System.out.println("Users in Tree after Adding Data:"+usersInTree.size());
        setDataInTreeSet(d2);
        System.out.println("Users in Tree after Adding Data:"+usersInTree.size());
        setDataInTreeSet(d1);
        System.out.println("Users in Tree after Adding Data:"+usersInTree.size());

        printDataInSet(usersInTree);
    }

}

public void setDataInSet(MyData userDetails){
    System.out.println("Setting Data in HashSet");
    usersInHash.add(userDetails);       
}

public void setDataInTreeSet(MyData userDetails){
    System.out.println("Setting Data in TreeSet");
    usersInTree.add(userDetails);
}

public void printDataInSet(Set<MyData> s){
    System.out.println("Printing Data");
    System.out.println("Size of the Set:"+s.size());
    for(MyData itorator: s){
        try{
            System.out.println("User Details:______");
            System.out.println("Name:"+itorator.getName());
            System.out.println("Mobile Number:"+itorator.getMobileNo());
            System.out.println("eMail:"+itorator.getEmail());
            System.out.println("Profession:"+itorator.getProfession());
            System.out.println("Sex:"+itorator.getSex());

        }catch(NullPointerException npe){
            System.out.println(npe.getMessage());
            npe.getStackTrace();
        }finally{
            System.out.println("EOD_____\n");
        }

    }

}
```

}

**Now the problem is in TreeSet I can only see the data of d7 only and nothing else is getting added to TreeSet**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my TreeSet not add anything beyond the first element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123336/why-does-my-treeset-not-add-anything-beyond-the-first-element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TreeSet` will use your `MyData.compareTo` implementation to compare elements. But you haven't implemented it - it always returns `0`. So as far as the `TreeSet` can tell, all `MyData` objects are equal. See the [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) javadoc for more info.

Note that the `HashSet` is working because it uses [`hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) and [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). Unlike `compareTo`, these have default implementations in the `Object` class, which are based on reference equality. I recommend you override these two methods and base them on the `MyData` fields instead. As it is, two different `MyData` objects with identical data will not be considered equal. (Most IDEs can auto-generate good `hashCode` and `equals` overrides based on specified fields.)

Comment: Thanks Paul, let me go through it and work on you suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on compareTo method. `return 0` treat equals `MyData`, which will add one `MyData` object at `TreeSet`.

```
public int compareTo(MyData o) {
   //Write correct compareTo contract for MyData.
}
```