# Why does my TreeSet not add anything beyond the first element?

Tags: java, set, treeset

I have several arrays in the form:

```
private static String[] patientNames = { "John Lennon", "Paul McCartney", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr" };
```

Then I make a TreeSet like this:

```
TreeSet<Patient> patTreeSet = new TreeSet<Patient>();
```

Where Patient is a different class that makes "Patient" objects.
Then I loop through each element in my arrays to create several patients and add them to my `patTreeSet` like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< patientNames.length; i++){
     Date dob = date.getDate("MM/dd/yyyy", patientBirthDates[i]);
     Patient p = new PatientImpl(patientNames[i], patientSSN[i], dob);

     patTreeSet.add(p);
}
```

But when I go to check my `patTreeSet.size()` it only returns "1" - why is this?

I know my objects are working well because when I try to do the same thing but with `ArrayList` instead, everything works fine. So I'm guessing I'm using the TreeSet wrong.

If it helps, Patient has a method called getFirstName(), and when I try to do the following:

```
Iterator<Patient> patItr = patTreeSet.iterator();

while(patItr.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(patItr.next().getFirstName());

}
```

Then only "John" prints, which obviously shouldn't be the case... So, am I totally misusing the TreeSet?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT** below

================PatientImpl Class====================

```
public class PatientImpl implements Patient, Comparable{

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String SSN;
    private Date dob;
    private int age;
    private int thisID;             
    public static int ID = 0;       



    public PatientImpl(String fullName, String SSN, Date dob){

        String[] name = fullName.split(" ");
        firstName = name[0];
        lastName = name[1];

        this.SSN = SSN;

        this.dob = dob;

        thisID = ID += 1;
    }

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object p) {

        //for some reason casting here and reassigning the value of p doesn't take care of the need to cast in the if statement...
        p = (PatientImpl) p;

        Boolean equal = false;
        //make sure p is a patient before we even compare anything
        if (p instanceof Patient) {

            Patient temp = (Patient) p;

            if (this.firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.getFirstName())) {
                if (this.lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.getLastName())) {
                    if (this.SSN.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.getSSN())) {
                        if(this.dob.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(((PatientImpl) p).getDOB().toString())){
                            if(this.getID() == temp.getID()){
                                equal = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         }
        return equal;
    }
```

and then all the getters are below, as well as the compareTo() method from the Comparable interface

Comment: Show us your `PatientImpl` class.

Comment: Paste the code for `Patient`

Comment: TreeSet - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_treeset_class.htm

Comment: The TreeSet relies on your Patient/PatientImpl equals/hashCode/compareTo methods. They should be correctly implemented according to Object/Comparable contracts.

Comment: You have omitted the most important part, which is the code for the `Patient` class. If `Patient` does not contain correct implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()` it will not work.

Comment: This may sound very amateurish, but I had no idea this class mattered! I've added it to the code above. Thanks for the willingness to help, everyone!

Comment: You have omitted a `hashCode` method, so Patients that your `equals` method considers equal have different `hashCode`s (the default implementation of hashCode). Implement one yourself. Since you use `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare, you need to ensure that the `hashCode` function also ignores case. So combine the hashCodes of `this.firstName.toUpperCase().hashCode()` instead of just `this.firstName.hashCode()`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt They are using a `TreeSet`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I see, my bad. Thanks for correcting. We should get a look at the `compareTo` method in that case.

Comment: I don't have a compareTo method, nor was I aware I needed to make one, and I'm certainly not sure where to begin with that. Is the point about the hashCode still relevant? I see why it might be, but if all the hashCodes of each patient are different, then there shouldn't be a problem with the TreeSet, right?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you put your objects in a `TreeSet`, you need to either provide an implementation of the `Comparator` interface in the constructor, or you need your objects to be of a class that implements `Comparable`.

You said you implement `compareTo` from the `Comparable` interface, but in your comment you say that you didn't, so am I correct in assuming that you just `return 0;` in the `compareTo` method? That would explain your problem, because TreeSet would then think that all your objects are 'the same' based on the `compareTo` method result.

Basically, in a `TreeSet`, your objects are maintained in a sorted order, and the sorting is determined by the outcome of the Comparable/Comparator method. This is used to quickly find duplicates in a TreeSet and has the added benefit that when you iterate over the TreeSet, you get the results in sorted order.

The Javadoc of `TreeSet` says:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be *consistent with equals* if it is
>   to correctly implement the `Set` interface.

The easiest way to achieve that is to let your `equals` method call the `compareTo` method and check if the result is `0`.

Given your `PatientImpl` class, I assume that you would want to sort patients first by their last name, then by their first name, and then by the rest of the fields in the class.

You could implement a `compareTo` method like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Patient))
        return -1;
    Patient temp = (Patient) o;
    int r = this.lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(temp.getLastName());
    if (r == 0)
        r = this.firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(temp.getFirstName());
    if (r == 0)
        r = this.SSN.compareToIgnoreCase(temp.getSSN());
    if (r == 0)
        r = this.dob.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(temp.getDOB().toString());
    if (r == 0)
        r = Integer.compare(this.getID(), temp.getID());
    return r;
}
```

I believe that would solve the problem you described.
I would advise you to read up (Javadoc or books) on `TreeSet` and `HashSet` and the importance of the `equals`, `compareTo` and `hashCode` methods.
If you want to put your objects in a Set or a Map, you need to know about these to implement that correctly.

**Note**
I based this `compareTo` method on your `equals` method.
You were comparing the date-of-birth by first calling toString. That's not a very good way of doing that - you can use the `equals` method in java.util.Date directly. In a compareTo method the problem gets worse because dates do not sort correctly when you sort them alphabetically.
`java.util.Date` also implements `Comparable` so you can replace that comparison in the method with:

```
    if (r == 0)
        r = this.dob.compareTo(temp.getDOB());
```

In addition, if any of the fields could be `null`, you need to check for that as well.

Comment: Erwin, I appreciate you taking your time for that thorough answer. It really helped. And you were right on several notes, specifically - when I implemented the Comparable interface in my PatientImpl class, I let it add the compareTo method automatically (with return 0), which made it seem like everything was equal. I changed that, and now it works!
Thanks for your points about the Date, and everything else! (I would plus 1 your answer if I had enough reputation points!) Cheers

Comment: The `compareTo` implementation returns 0 in the end. It should be `r`, right?

Comment: @jayeffkay You're right, funny that this wasn't caught for 3 years. I've also updated the comparison of the id's - using Integer.compare is better than subtraction because it avoids possible integer overflow conditions.