# Treeset of exam printed

Tags: java, class, object, set, treeset

Hello i've these 3 classes:
Here i put the name of a student and the exams he gave

```
package traccia50719;

import java.util.*;

public class Lab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Studente studente = inserimento();
        System.out.println("fine inserimento\n");
        
        studente.print();
        System.out.println("\nfine programma");
    }

    private static Studente inserimento() {
        Studente s = null;
        Esame esame=null;
        System.out.println("\nmatricola:");
        Scanner mat = new Scanner(System.in);
        int matricola= mat.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\ncognome:");
        Scanner cog = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cognome= cog.next();
        System.out.println("\nNome:");
        Scanner nom = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nome= nom.next();
        s= new Studente(matricola, cognome, nome);

        do{
            System.out.println("\ncodice esame:");
            Scanner cod = new Scanner(System.in);
            int codicesame= cod.nextInt();
            if(codicesame==0){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("\nNome esame:");
            Scanner nomes = new Scanner(System.in);
            String nomesame= nomes.next();
            System.out.println("\nvoto esame:");
            Scanner vot = new Scanner(System.in);
            int votoesame= vot.nextInt();
            esame = new Esame(codicesame,nomesame,votoesame);
            s.addEsame(esame);
            
        }while(true);
        
        return s;
    }

}
```

In this class i've  the student with the constructor but when i try to print exams with iterator i have only one exam printed. Why?

```
package traccia50719;

import java.util.*;

public class Studente {

    private int matricola;
    private String cognome;
    private String nome;
    private Set<Esame> esami = new TreeSet<Esame>();
    
    public Studente(int matricola, String cognome, String nome){
        this.matricola=matricola;
        this.cognome=cognome;
        this.nome=nome;

    }

    public void addEsame(Esame e){
        this.esami.add(e);
    }
    
    public void  print(){
        System.out.println("\nmatricola:" + this.matricola);
        System.out.println("\ncognome:" + this.cognome);
        System.out.println("\nnome:" + this.nome);
        Iterator<Esame> i = this.esami.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            Esame e = (Esame) i.next();
            e.stampaesame();
            
        }


    }
    
    
}
```

This is the 3 class Exam and i've stampaEsame() that print name and the result of the exam

```
package traccia50719;

public class Esame implements Comparable{

    private int codice;
    private String nome;
    private int voto;
    
    public Esame(int codice, String nome, int voto){
        this.codice=codice;
        this.nome=nome;
        this.voto=voto;
    }
    
    public void stampaesame(){
        System.out.println("\n nome esame:" +this.nome);
        System.out.println("\n voto esame:" +this.voto);

    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Esame esa =  (Esame) o;
        if(this.codice==esa.codice){
            return true;    
        }else return false;
        }
    

    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Having `compareTo` always `return 0` is not a good idea because it implies all objects are equal. Do the different `Esame` have different `codice`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TreeSet only adding one value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086153/treeset-only-adding-one-value)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line with `esami` like this.

```
private List<Esame> esami = new List<Esame>();
```

If it works like this, then the problem was with the way you override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods for the `Esami` class. Due to this `TreeSet` is treting all of your inserts as being the same element and as a set it can only contain one instance of the same element.

Remeber, `hashCode()` and `equals()` must be [overridden together](https://crunchify.com/how-to-override-equals-and-hashcode-method-in-java/#:%7E:text=if%20you%20override%20equals%2C%20you,in%20both%20of%20these%20methods.) ;)

Comment: done but don't work, i've overrided hashCode and equals :(

Comment: public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

Then the problem lies in this method, which says that your Esami object is equal to any object what you should create is something like this https://www.baeldung.com/java-compareto

Comment: @user9859592 if my answer solved your problem, please both mark it as accepted and upvote, so its easier for others to find and reuse it in their work.